# Is it possible to use google DLP to create a bad words filter

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

Working on nodejs backend with google products, I am trying to make use of google DLP to filter out bad words, so that after users send a message request, the backend can send response to the frontend if the message contains bad words. But the DLP seems only scan source from within BigQuery, Google cloud storage or Cloud datastore. Is there an api that can scan the bad words within DLP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the content methods for that.

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-method-types#content-methods

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer from google [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-hybrid-jobs#types)